# not able to hash password in Expo IOS App

Tags: ios, mysql, node.js, expo, hashcode

I am building an Expo App for IOS Phone. I have added login page which provides reset password mechanism. I have used Node.js program to reset the password and the new resetted password is saved as hash password using bcrypt (ex: `$2b$05$cMUtC/1WHxzGNqDTJcCBJOf9i7D6ad57jKyYqChLF0Vvji1A2mzIq` for `Test123456`) inside Mysql database. This is working well and good. Below is the node.js program:

users.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection = require('../database.js');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var randtoken = require('rand-token');
//send email
function sendEmail(email, token) {
var email = email;
var token = token;
var mail = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: 'gmail',
auth: {
user: '*******@gmail.com', // Your email id
pass: '*******' // Your password
}
});
var mailOptions = {
from: 'abc@tech.com',
to: email,
subject: 'Reset Password Link - Tutsmake.com',
html: '<p>You requested for reset password, kindly use this <a 
href="http://localhost:4000/reset-password?token=' + token + '">link</a> to reset 
your password</p>'
 };
 mail.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
 if (error) {
 console.log(1)
  } else {
  console.log(0)
  }
  });
   }
  /* home page */
  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
  title: 'Forget Password Page'
  });
  });
  /* send reset password link in email */
  router.post('/reset-password-email', function(req, res, next) {
  var email = req.body.email;
   connection.query('SELECT * FROM JTGDB.UserInfo WHERE email ="' + email + '"', 
   function(err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   var type = ''
   var msg = ''
  console.log(result[0]);
  if (result[0].Email.length > 0) {
  var token = randtoken.generate(20);
  var sent = sendEmail(email, token);
  if (sent != '0') {
  var data = {
      token: token
  }
   connection.query('UPDATE JTGDB.UserInfo SET ? WHERE email ="' + email + '"', data, 
   function(err, result) {
   if(err) throw err
   })
   type = 'success';
    msg = 'The reset password link has been sent to your email address';
   } else {
   type = 'error';
    msg = 'Something goes to wrong. Please try again';
    }
    } else {
    console.log('2');
    type = 'error';
    msg = 'The Email is not registered with us';
    }
    req.flash(type, msg);
    res.redirect('/');
    });
    })
    /* reset page */
    router.get('/reset-password', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('reset-password', {
    title: 'Reset Password Page',
     token: req.query.token
     });
     });
   /* update password to database */
  router.post('/update-password', function(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.body.token;
  var password = req.body.password;
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM JTGDB.UserInfo WHERE token ="' + token + '"', 
  function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var type
  var msg
  if (result.length > 0) {
   var saltRounds = 5;
  bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
  bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
  var data = {
  password: hash
  }
  connection.query('UPDATE JTGDB.UserInfo SET ? WHERE email ="' + result[0].Email + 
   '"', data, function(err, result) {
  if(err) throw err
  });
  });
  });
  type = 'success';
  msg = 'Your password has been updated successfully';
  } else {
  console.log('2');
  type = 'success';
  msg = 'Invalid link; please try again';
  }
  req.flash(type, msg);
  res.redirect('/');
  });
   })
  module.exports = router;
```

But in Expo App, I want to hash the password that we enter in the login page and compare with the database hash password and then let the user to log into the App.

I have added a post request in app.js to get password from expo app and convert to hash code and compare it with database password to let user log in.Below is the app.js code .

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var flash = require('express-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const createError = require('http-errors');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var app = express();


/* hash password from database to expo App  */
app.post('/hash-password', function(req, res, next) {
const password = req.body.password;
console.log('Password is '+password)
var saltRounds = 5;
 //var hash = bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds, function(err, salt) {
bcrypt.hash(password, salt, function(err, hash) {
var data = {
password: hash
}
console.log(data);
})
})
})

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(session({ 
secret: '********',
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }
}))

app.use(flash());
app.use('/', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : 
{};

// render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
 res.render('error');
});

 app.listen(4000, function () {
 console.log('Node app is running on port 4000');
  });

 module.exports = app;
```

I checked the code by sending password from postman ,but I am getting the below error:

[image: postman input]

Comment: You should be hashing your password in your API. Your app's code is visible if the apk / ipa is inspected, so you don't really want to be exposing that code unnecessarily.

Comment: You are telling me to convert the database password from hash password to plain text and compare the password when we call Node JS API inside Expo App?How to convert 'Test123456'( when user enters the login password )to '$2b$05$cMUtC/1WHxzGNqDTJcCBJOf9i7D6ad57jKyYqChLF0Vvji1A2mzIq' to compare in Expo App?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting passing the password as plain text to the API and then hashing it in the API and comparing it there.

Comment: I have used a post request in app.js to get value from expo app to hash and compare.I have edited the above code to add the hashing code.But it is not taking value from postman.Please refer the edited question.